# Geb with browser sample running example

Tags: geb

I searched google for geg+browser stack real time example but couldnot found any working example. Could you please help me in getting a real time example for the same ?

Comment: Can you please tell us what did you try so far? Did you setup everything correctly?

Comment: Why you not use default example on GEB wiki?